# Get rid of square paging icons in flexslider

Tags: flexslider

In flexslider's paging control, the icons are initially squares. After loading (I guess?) they turn round, like I want them to be. Please see attached screensnip.

How do I turn this behavior off, so the paging icons are round from the start?

I'm using the following options:

```
$('#sdn').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    slideShow: false        
});
```

I have tried a:

```
start: function (slider) {
    $('body').removeClass('loading');
}
```

with no effect.

[[image: unwanted behaviour]]

Answer (score 0):

This is also recurring on a website I'm working on. I notice it only occurs on Chrome Version 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit), OSX Yosemite.

Haven't tested on other Chromes yet.

Square issue not occurring in Firefox nor Safari.